# Regarding Salesforce Connected App

Tags: salesforce1-app, connected-apps

I want to understand the process of the dynamic registration of the connected app. How we directly register a connected app after login into the salesforce system and then retrieve data.
How one connected app is shared among different salesforce account?

Comment: Do you want to have like Workbench?

Comment: Yes, something similar but on UI like import2 wizard or AWS appflow.

Answer (score 2):

You use either the [Web Server OAuth Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) or [User-Agent OAuth Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5). When a user first clicks "Accept" to allow the connection when logging in, the org for which they logged in to will automatically "install" the Connected App so that administrators can allow/block it and alter security settings.

There is nothing you need to do as a developer to make this happen; it's fully automatic. As far as retrieving data, you simply need to call the relevant [REST APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm) using the access token you received when your flow completed. The details are in the documentation, linked above.

The Connected App uses a Client ID that uniquely identifies it. This is how Salesforce knows which icon to display and which permissions that the app is requesting.

Each flow is slightly different, but the general idea is that your app points to a Salesforce URL, which prompts the user to log in. Once they complete the login, the flow is redirected back to your app with a token. This token is then either used directly (User-Agent), or traded for a separate token to complete the process (Web Server).